# Is there an infinite field of characteristic 2 whose multiplicative group is torsion free and (direct-sum) indecomposable?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, galois-theory, fields

Let $F$ be a infinite field of characteristic 2 whose multiplicative group $F^*$ is torsion free. I would like to conclude that $F^*$ is decomposable or find an example where $F^*$ is indecomposable.

If $F^*$ is (direct-sum) indecomposable, then:

- $F$ cannot be purely transcendental over $F_2$
- $F^*$ has infinite rank.

I don't know anything beyond that.

Comment: FWIW, my instinct would be to try looking at something like the field of Hahn series over $F_2$ with value group $\mathbb{Q}$. But I'm not sure how to calculate the multiplicative group, and it's getting late where I am.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: It seems to me that this field is perfect and henselian, hence every element has $n$th roots for every $n$ (since this trivially holds for the residue field). So, the multiplicative group is just a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. I think there might be more hope with a *discrete* value group.

Comment: And I’m talking nonsense with discrete valuations, because if the value group is free, $K^\times$ splits as $O^\times\oplus\Gamma$.

Comment: Hi Sunil. I don't really have any ideas, but I wondered if you knew any examples of fields (apart from finite fields of order one more than a prime power) where the multiplicative group is indecomposable?

Comment: @ Jeremy Rickard: Yes. Take the field of 9 elements, for instance. More generally, I know exactly which finite fields have indecomposable multiplicative group. I can prove the following result.
Let $k$ be a finite field. Then, the group of units in $k$ is indecomposable if and only if $k$ is one of the following fields:
$\mathbf{F}_2$, $\mathbf{F}_9$,
$\mathbf{F}_q$ where $q$ is a Fermat prime, or
 $\mathbf{F}_{p+1}$ where $p$ is a Mersenne prime.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard: I can also prove that an infinite field of odd characteristic cannot have an indecomposable multiplicative group.

Comment: OK. Your finite examples are the ones I ruled out by my parenthetical "apart from". Is the odd characteristic proof easy to explain? And what about characteristic zero? Or characteristic two with torsion? Is it true that the multiplicative group of a field is the direct sum of a torsion-free and a torsion group, maybe? These are not entirely idle questions. I was wondering how important your conditions were, and whether trying to prove something more general like "Every infinite field has a decomposable multiplicative group" was a waste of time?

Comment: If $F^\times$ is indecomposable and not torsion-free, then it must be $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ (in which case $F$ is finite) or $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$. (This is a fact about abelian groups that doesn't use that $F^\times$ is the multiplicative group of a field.) One can argue that the latter case cannot occur. If $F^\times$ is torsion free, then one must have $1 = -1$, and the characteristic is 2. In general, the torsion subgroup of $F^\times$ need not be a summand; see  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73751/torsion-group-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reference! First counterexample published by my mathematical grandfather in the year of my birth: I should probably have known about that!